# execute MATLAB using MLApp.MLAppClass.FEval in C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

Do you have an example doing this kind of communication.
Any simple example, besides from documentation ( real world example ) would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/jmi-java-to-matlab-interface/ and its follow-up articles - they are about Java but the interface should be fairly similar to C#.